# How to increase the page turn speed

Tags: pdf, ebook-reader

Are there some general rules how to create pdf documents in order to achieve an optimal page turn speed?
 I recently created few pdf documents (without graphics) using Microsoft Word and realized that my ebook reader (SONY) leafs through them at a slower pace compared with some pdf documents containing more pages and graphics.
What features of pdf documents or ebook readers affect the page turn speed?
How these feature should be configured to increase the page turn speed?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a few major items that could affect PDF document rendering speeds in the general case. These items are, in order of severity:

- Vector graphics - this is by far the worst offender. Too many vector graphics could bring document rendering speeds to a crawl
- High-resolution images - even if the images in the actual document appear small, the originals, stored in the document, could be high resolution. This leads to slow rendering speeds as well
- Font problems - this category is expanded on below

I imagine issues with fonts is what comes into play here. The rendering speed can be affected by the number of fonts in a PDF document. Also the use of multi-byte and cid fonts sometimes could trip up a mobile viewer.

Another problem could be the version of word used. Older versions don't do as good of a job generating PDF documents, as newer versions.